# Is it possible to enable the Chinese Cortana on Windows phone?

Tags: cortana, language-setting

This is the Chinese version of Cortana:

[image]

Is there any way I can enable it? Changing my phone to Chinese doesn't work.

Comment: Did you change both the region and language?

Comment: Yes, I set language to `中国（中华人民共和国）` and region to `China`.

Comment: In fact, setting region to China disables Cortana.

Answer (score 1):

Cortana is available in China. But the language must be set to **Chinese (simplified)** or **中文 (简体)**. Bing translate indiactes that you have set the language to *China (People's Republic of China)* or 中国（中华人民共和国） which is not supported by Cortana. In case you want to know Chinese (simplified) is located next to China (People's Republic of China).

So go to *Settings -> Language* and choose 中文 (简体).

Now Cortana should work for you.

Reference : [Microsoft.com - Cortana's availablity](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026948/windows-10-cortanas-regions-and-languages)